# JAVA_HOME path updated for version 11, java version in the cmd still showing 8

Tags: java

I had recently installed java 11 and set all the necessary paths in the system environment variables. 
[image]

why does my java -version show the old java installed. Do i need to do something else to get his updated.

Comment: have you updated your environment settings?

Comment: try `where java` and take a look at the path (it's most probably an oracle path set). then delete this path from your environment variables.

Comment: yes environment setting have been updated @stultuske

Comment: @bbortt i have deleted all the oracle related path . i'm aware it causes a hindrance.

Comment: still, what does `where java` result in?

Comment: @bbortt couldn't paste the snapshot of the outcome. Hence,
C:\>where java
C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.6\bin\java.exe

Comment: @AnantMajhi Enable the latest installed version of Java in the Java Control Panel : [link](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/update_runtime_settings.xml#:~:text=In%20the%20Java%20Control%20Panel%2C%20click%20on%20the%20Java%20tab.&text=Verify%20that%20the%20latest%20Java,by%20checking%20the%20Enabled%20box.&text=Click%20OK%20in%20Java%20Control,Java%20installed%20in%20your%20system.)

Comment: @AnantMajhi hence delete `C:\Windows\System32\java.exe`. This is the one picked up and as it seems is still version 8. It doesn't belong into the `System32` folder. And maybe also find out how it got there. (cmd picks results one after another and the `System32` path is on top of the queue)

Comment: @bbortt yes just did that. Now its pointing to the java 11 . Thanks a lot

Comment: @AnantMajhi no Problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add %JAVA_HOME%\bin to your path.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that older Java versions put a copy of java.exe and javaw.exe in a directory and reference it from there. That directory, I think, does not contain javac.exe so javac -version is fine but java -version is not fine.

So, java -version is still referring to old java.exe which is there somewhere in your file system.

Do "where java.exe" on command prompt to find where you have java.exe.

Then delete the older versions of java.exe and javaw.exe. Then try doing java -version again.

Comment: Or instead of deleting the old versions, you could remove the old %JAVA_HOME%/bin directory from the %PATH%. Most likely, both the new and old JRE are in the path.

Answer (score 0):

It is worked for me:

Steps:

1. You need to add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to your path
2. Do `"where java.exe"` on Command Prompt to find where you have `java.exe`
3. Then delete the older versions of `java.exe` and `javaw.exe`. Then try doing `java -ve2sion` again.